# Алгоритмы с битовыми полями

Tags: c, алгоритм, c++

Какие алгоритмы существуют с использованием битовых полей, инициализированых в структурах?

Comment: Вы хотели спросить, для чего используются битовые поля?

Comment: да , именно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку речь идет про **битовые поля**, а не **битовые вектора**, то стоит привести более-менее адекватный пример их использования:

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
       struct
       {
           unsigned long mantissa: 23;
           unsigned long exponent: 8;
           unsigned long sign: 1;
       } float_parts;
       float all;
    };
} _float __attribute__((__packed__));
```

Здесь использование битовых полей позволяет удобным образом получить доступ к внутреннему содержимому числа в соответствии IEEE754 *(там, конечно, есть еще проблемы `endianness`, однако это не столь принципиально)*.

Раньше битовые поля *(например, в первых вариациях игровых движков `idTech`)* использовались достаточно часто для экономии памяти на хранение каких-либо данных.

**Сейчас их использование, на мой взгляд, бессмысленно, да и, вообще говоря, доступ к полям такой структуры занимает больше времени из-за необходимости `masking'a`.**

---

С более практической точки зрения рекомендую ознакомиться со статьей [**`vector<bool>` : More problems, better solutions,**](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/N1211.pdf) которая объясняет, чем плох `vector<bool>`.

Также стоит научиться пользоваться `std::bitset` и `boost::dynamic_bitset`.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно битовые поля используются, если нужно сэкономить память на хранении данных, которые можно хранить в одном бите. `vector<bool>` занимает в 8 раз (или другое число, в зависимости от платформы) меньше памяти, чем простой массив `bool[]`.
Также, если я не ошибаюсь, цвет вершины в красно-черных деревьях хранится одним битом.